# the event window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener fires only once

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, addeventlistener, darkmode

I try to change the mode light/dark automatically according to the preference user on his device through addEventListener, but the event is fire only once.
Iam working with ionic and angular.

```
Angular CLI: 14.2.3
Node: 16.17.0
Package Manager: npm 8.19.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 14.2.3
... cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------       
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1402.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.2.3
@angular-devkit/core            14.2.3
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.2.3
@schematics/angular             14.2.3
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.7.4

Ionic version: 6.20.1
```

In service.ts:

```
setListenerTheme(): void {
    window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').onchange = (e) => {
      console.log("ESCUCHANDO CAMBIOS EN THEME")
      const buttonToggleTheme = document.querySelector('#themeToggle');

      buttonToggleTheme.toggleAttribute('checked');
    };
  }

  toggleTheme(event: any): void {
    this.dark_mode = event.detail.checked;
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark', event.detail.checked);
  }
```

In app.component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userService.setListenerTheme();
  }

}
```

Comment: I forgot, iam already  tried the method of the official documentation on https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/dark-mode, but still no working.

Answer (score 0):

try `addEventListener` instead of `onChange`. It might solve the problem because it's working fine on my ionic 5 and ionic 6 app. like this:

```
const prefersDark = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
prefersDark.addEventListener('change', (mediaQuery) => {
      this.toggleDarkMode(mediaQuery.matches);
    });
```

also make sure you do everything based on the boolean value of `mediaQuery.matches`, it can be true or false, meaning dark mode is on or off. if it doesn't solve your problem please explain your problem in more details; by firing once do you mean "the first time you turn on dark mode" or "the first time you turn on or off dark mode". also check it on different devices and outputs.

Comment: Hi! AmiriAli, thanks for your answer, i tried on other device and works, it seems like no working in my samsung a21s and the virtual devices, i dont know why. But anyway thanks!